# How can I determine if the script is being executed within a system or qx call in Perl?

Tags: perl

In Perl, is it possible to determine if a script is being executed within another script (presumably via `system` or `qx`)?

```
$ cat foo.pl
print "foo";
print "\n" if not $in_qx;  # or the like.
```

I realize this is not applicable if the script was being run via `exec`.

I know for certain that `system` runs the process as a `fork` and I know `fork` can return a value that is variable depending on whether you are in the parent or the child process. Not certain about `qx`.

Regardless, I'm not certain how to figure out if I'm in a `fork`ed process without actually performing a `fork`.

Comment: What platform(s) are you running on?

Comment: "Standard" linux, nothing particularly special.

Comment: The thing I thought was interesting is that fork will give you a 0 or $PID depending on if you are the parent or the child respectively. I had hoped there was an easy way to see this. But so far it looks like the best answer is a kludge. Unforunate, though Owens has an interesting point that all processes are forked and walking the tree can get whacky.

Comment: Now that I think about it, `system` does a fork twice I believe. One for the shell, and then another when the shell executes the requested program.

Comment: Can you detail what you're trying to distinguish between?  I presume that you're asking 'Can I tell if my script was run from the command line, or from another application I didn't write and have no control over'?

Comment: @ijw: I think that'd be a good way to word it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All processes are forked from another process (except init).  You can sort of tell if the program was run from `open`, `qx//`, `open2`, or `open3` by using the `isatty` function from [POSIX](http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html), but there is no good way to determine if you are being run by `system` without looking at the process tree, and even then it can get murky (for instance `system "nohup", "./foo.pl"` will not have the calling perl process as its parent).

Answer (score 5):

You could check "who's your daddy", using "getppid" (get parent id). Then check if your parent id is a perl script with pgrep or similar.

Comment: getppid (and most of the get* functions) aren't implemented on all platforms. Even where they are, you would have to determine if the PID belonged to an instance of perl, the shell, or something else.

Comment: Well he's running on some standard linux so this is probably no issue there. Anyway it's some sort of kludge, there isn't any sure and clean approach here.

Answer (score 2):

Do you control the caller? The simplest thing to do would be to pass an argument, e.g. `--isforked`.

Comment: No, not really. My script is acting as a wrapper for another, I don't really have the ability to modify the arguments.